# More privileges for reputation between 5K and 10K

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, privileges, 10k-tools

I just turned 10K in Stackoverflow. I was quite impressed to see how many privileges you get when passing this threshold: [Access To Moderator Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

At the same time, I felt that some of these privileges could be gradually moved to lower reputation, so that we have more features given on the loooong path between 5K and 10K, for example on 7,5K.

For example, this is the one I think that could be moved:

> Aside from this, you get the ability to do inline tag edits on
>   questions. Hover your mouse next to the tags and you should see a
>   "edit tags" button:

Do you agree with me?

Comment: Who and how updated my question with the "*this question may already have an answer here"* message? I did not and the history does not show anyone apart from me.

Comment: A certain review queue that needs some work might be a good candidate to move down to 7.5k or something.

Comment: Uhms I just got a couple of downvotes. Downvotes meaning you don't agree or am I missing something?

Comment: @fedorqui as a question author, you're currently the only one who sees this message (that's by design). Others don't see it, you may test it by viewing your post unregistered. It is caused by a flag / vote suggesting to close your question as a dupe. When (if) your question gets dupe-closed, such a message will be displayed to all other users, too. Until it isn't, you're the only one who can see it

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, @gnat, I checked it with "incognito window" of Chrome and happened exactly what you said!

Comment: @fedorqui you're welcome. Another tip, while I have your attention: as an author, you can also vote close if you feel that suggested dupe has better chance to succeed. Yesterday, I dupe-closed two of my own questions that way - btw that's when I observed that "message shown only to OP" myself. One of my questions even obtained an extra upvote while it was being closed :)

Comment: Thanks @gnat, I just performed the last close vote. My goal is to draw attention to the question, so hopefully this way I get a little more. As it is a proposal, to be closed is not a big deal as there is not real need of answers.